# ball duplicated by symmetrical mirrors

Tags: animation, mirror

My goal is to symmetrically place mirror modifiers on a sphere where each mirror object of the modify is an empty one in order to duplicate this animated sphere
no initial sphere duplication
1st duplication 2 spheres
2nd duplication 4 spheres
3rd duplication 8 spheres
etc ....

I am looking for tutorial or blend file realizing this **perfectly**

I did it with mirror edit but I can not do it properly

see link file blend not correct: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vU5ZEYNjSGCeqgB5dQDbDoZjenU3LDHH/view?usp=sharing

I would like the trajectory of the sphere to be like that in this image
see link file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LiFCCM9qbVKixzwTjazSkdRRUlSvtU41/view?usp=sharing

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Better use an **Array Modifier**?

Comment: I downloaded your .blend file but I am unsure what it is you are trying to achieve. Can you add images to your question explaining what you need and how it should work. Try an show the simplest example.

Comment: I would create the pattern in a Curve and then use Duplivert to place a Sphere at each vertex. You can import the Curve as an SVG if it is easier to create in another program. Each vertex location can be edited in the Propertied panel if you have the math. Or you could look at Python and script the creation of the mathematically correct curve.